# jQuery replace text inside anchor

Tags: jquery

im creating a like system but i have ran into a problem, with when the user presses like the "like" text should change to "remove like"

the data comes from a php query so theres many items with same class

```
<table class="UserHistoryTable">
<td data-rowtype="stat" data-rowuser="1" data-rowid="1" class="UserHistoryTableTD">
<a href="#" class="like">Like</a></td>
</table>
```

data-rowuser is the id of the user pressing the like button, data-rowid is the id of the activity
what i wanna do is, when someone presses the "like" link, it should change to "Remove like" 
i have tried with this code:

```
$('.like').click(function(){
var the_id = $(this).parent().data('rowid')
var user_id = $(this).parent().data('rowuser')
var user_id = $(this).parent().data('rowtype')
   $.ajax({
      url: "like.php",
      data: "action=likestat" + "&id=" + the_id + "&uid=" + user_id,
         success:function(response){
            var findtext = $('.UserHistoryTableTD > .like', this);
            $(findtext).replaceWith("Remove like");
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple problems.  `this` won't still be the same value as you want in the success handler (it will have a different value related to the ajax call).  And the `>` selector means direct child and `.like` is not a direct child of the parent table.  If you save the value of `this` in a local variable, you can just use it directly in the ajax handler.

Change the code to this:

```
$('.like').click(function(){
    var the_id = $(this).parent().data('rowid')
    var user_id = $(this).parent().data('rowuser')
    var self = this;  // save for use in success handler
    $.ajax({
        url: "like.php",
        data: "action=likestat" + "&id=" + the_id + "&uid=" + user_id,
        success:function(response){
            $(self).html("Remove like");
       }
   });
});
```

You could also DRY it up a bit like this:

```
$('.like').click(function(){
    var $self = $(this);              // save this for use later
    var $td = $self.closest("td");    // find correct parent, regardless of other markup
    $.ajax({
        url: "like.php",
        data: "action=likestat" + "&id=" + $td.data('rowid') + "&uid=" + $td.data('rowuser'),
        success:function(response){
            $self.html("Remove like");
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: @samura - you have to save away the value of `this` in a local variable so you can use it in the success handler (because `this` will have a different value in the success handler).  Since we need `$(this)` in several places, I save that instead of just `this`.  One popular convention for a saved `this` variable is `self`.  Another popular convention for saved jQuery objects is to preface them with `$`.  Thus we end up with `$self` as the variable name (a jQuery object that represents `this`).

Comment: wow that was even more than i asked of! thanks for shortning my code, and for helping me :) (i love when people help me)

Comment: how would you write it if you had to remove it again?
would you use an if statement ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "remove it again".

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `this` inside success, so you save a var with `$(this)` outside your success event.

```
$('.like').click(function(){
var like_button = $(this);
var the_id = $(this).parent().data('rowid');
var user_id = $(this).parent().data('rowuser');
var user_id = $(this).parent().data('rowtype'); // something is wrong here :s
   $.ajax({
      url: "like.php",
      data: "action=likestat" + "&id=" + the_id + "&uid=" + user_id,
         success:function(response){
            like_button.replaceWith("Remove like");
       }
   });
});
```

(Edited as suggested by James comment)

And something is wrong in line number 4/5.

Comment: As you've already passed `this` into jQuery in the first line it's unnecessary to do it again in the `success` function. But +1 for being the first to answer correctly!

Comment: shit thank you for pointing out my failure.. i couldnt understand why that part didnt work :/ thanks 
and thanks a ton for the answer! it worked beautyfully :)

Comment: although it removes the link, thats ok, but i cant pass html into the value

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do:

```
$(this).html("Remove like");
```

inside your click event handler.

Comment: well id like to be sure that the like got inserted into the database before editing text, but this option works on the other hand :) thanks

Comment: `this` won't have the correct value in the ajax success handler.

Answer (score 0):

It can be more easilly done using jQuery's `.html()` function.
http://jsfiddle.net/Hz7WY/

Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.like').click(function(){
var the_id = $(this).parent().data('rowid')
var user_id = $(this).parent().data('rowuser')
var user_id = $(this).parent().data('rowtype')
      $('.like').html('Unlike');
});
</script>
```

Body:

```
<table class="UserHistoryTable">
<td data-rowtype="stat" data-rowuser="1" data-rowid="1" class="UserHistoryTableTD">
<a href="#" class="like">Like</a></td>
</table>
```